# Counting the total number of fields in form filled by the user

Tags: jquery

I am using this below code to count the total number of fields entered by user in form, however it is giving me the count of radio buttons if they are not checked, i want to count the radio buttons only if they are checked in total number of fields entered by the user

```
var filledInputs = $(':input').filter(function() {
    return !!this.value;
}).length;
```

Please suggest

Comment: Please include all your html code

Answer (score 1):

Your current code does not work because all radio buttons have a `value` regardless of whether they are checked or not. To make `filter()` work you'd need to interrogate the `checked` property of a `:checkbox` element:

```
var filledInputs = $(':checkbox').filter(function() {
  return this.checked;
}).length;
```

That being said, you can make the code much more simple by using the `:checked` selector - there's then no need for the `filter()` at all:

```
var filledInputs = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
```

Comment: I am using below HTML                                                                               
 var totalFilledFields = $(target).closest('.modal-content').find(':input:not([type=hidden])').not('button').filter(function () { return $(this).val() != ""; }).length;

Comment: Ok, is there an issue with that? Secondly, please edit your question if you need to add further information. Code in comments is almost unreadable

Comment: var totalFilledFields = $(target).closest('.modal-content').find(':input:not([type=hidden])').not('button').filter(function () { return $(this).val() != ""; }).length;

Comment: Also i modified the code as suggested by you above , so it is giving me the correct count if user selects the checkbox, however it is not counting any other fields expect radio button which is entered by user.

Comment: What are the other fields? It would help if you could show a full sample of your HTML along with information about what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am able to achieve the scenario by using var filledInputs = $(':input').filter(function() {
    if($(this).is(':radio'))
        return this.checked:

    return !!this.value;
}).length;

Comment: Also have one more condition that i am counting total number of fields in form whether filled or not. 'code' var totalFields = $(target).closest('.modal- content').find(':input:not([type=hidden])').not('button').le‌​ngth; So I am getting the correct result, the only issue is here that if i have two radio buttons under single selection of label, so is it possible to count both of them as one